# How to protect XML like a feed

Tags: php, javascript, xml, security

I have a `xml` file used by a `swf` to read and display information, but I would like to protect it from viewing the raw file, but keep swf access to view info.

Is there a way to do this, maybe php, javascript?...

Comment: If it's available for access from the Internet by your Flash code, it's available to anybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion any thing that goes to a browser can be hijacked. What your strategy should be is to make it harder to do. Here are possible cases:

- To protect your data from being sniffed on the wire use SSL ("https://") for you web service
- Implement application authentication like 2-legged OAuth. This will give you a more granular control over what apps accessing your service.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an .htaccess rule (if using an apache server) and prevent direct access...

Comment: Excuse me, what can I do if I do not have direct access to that file, any other way?

Comment: you can block a direct access with the browser and still be able to use it via a script; anyway, there's a similar topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682435/